# Fail to change style of requested vector tiles

Tags: mapbox, openstreetmap

I am trying to request vector tiles in a custom style, using the following request:

`map.addMapTiles('https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?style=mapbox://styles/[my_username]/[my_styleid]&access_token=pk.ey[my_key]');`

(map is an OSMBuildings object. (https://github.com/OSMBuildings/OSMBuildings))

I still see the map in the default style ([see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3enhq.jpg)) of the strees-v8-map.

Same happens when I try to use one of mapbox default styles e.g. style=mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10

I hope someone can help me!
Thanks a lot!

Luise

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#retrieve-vector-tiles) this seems to be the expected behaviour. If you "optimize" the vector tiles you are requesting with `https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?` by adding the `style` GET parameter, the tileset `v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8` will only be optimized, to be used with the style you specified.

It is still up to you to use this style. But you do not have to use that style. You can also use another one that the tileset has not been optimized for.

Documentation:

> Retrieve style-optimized vector tiles
> Vector tiles can be further optimized by including the style ID with the tile request. If the style parameter is provided, the sources, filters, minzoom, and maxzoom properties of that style are analyzed, and data that won't be visible on the map is removed from the vector tile. Mapbox GL JS can request style-optimized vector tiles that are hosted on Mapbox with a Mapbox Style JSON.

> Unused layers and features are removed from optimized styles. If you plan to dynamically change the style at runtime using Mapbox GL JS or a Mapbox mobile SDK, broadening filters and zoom ranges won't work the same way since any data that isn't visible with the loaded style also won't be included in the data.